# Isolate one result from XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, cordova

I'm programming an app in Phonegap, using HTML(5), CSS3 and Javscript (and friends). I have a problem though: Parsing the XML works great, I get all the items in the XML file on my screen and I can style them through CSS.

Every XML item has a title, image, teaser and "lees-verder" ("read more" which mostly only contains an embedded video).

This is the script I use to view the title, image and teaser of every item:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "webzap.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    var urllist = $(this).find('link').text();
                    var node = urllist.substring(urllist.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
                    var id = node;
                    var total = $(this).find('id').text();
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                    var brief = $(this).find('teaser').text();
                    var long = $(this).find('lees-verder').text();
                    var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                    var img = $(this).find('image').text(); 
                    $('<a href="http://www.flabber.nl/node/'+id+'"><div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div></a>').appendTo('.class2');
                    $('<h2 class="title_list" style="margin-top: 40px;"></h2>').html(title).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<h6 class="pubDate"></h6>').html('Dit is node nummer '+id).appendTo('#link_'+id);                        
                    $('<div class="introtekst"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<div class="introtekst"></div>').html(total).appendTo('#link_'+id);                      
                    $('<div class="screenshot"></div>').html('<img src="'+img+'" height="120"/><br />').appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<h2 class="title"></h2>').html(title).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    /*$('<div class="content"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id); */
                    /*$('<div class="introtekst" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">Open volledige website</a>').appendTo('#link_'+id);*/
                });
            }

        });
    });
 </script>
```

What I now want is that I click on an item, which then opens in a new page and shows the title, image, teaser AND "lees-verder". Another possibility would be if all XML-content disappears when a user clicks on an item, except the item he/she clicked on. The "lees-verder" should than also be loaded, because when I simply hide it with "display: none;" in CSS, it loads them anyway and slows down the app drastically. I have of course been searching the web, but I can't find what I need.

Here is a piece of my XML file if that makes it easier for you lot. :)

```
<item>
<title>Wat is een schrikkeljaar?</title>
<link>
http://www.flabber.nl/linkdump/video/wat-is-een-schrikkeljaar-10653
</link>
<teaser>
<![CDATA[
Het is 29 februari, tijd om uit te leggen wat een schrikkeljaar is.
]]>
</teaser>
<lees-verder>
<![CDATA[
<p><iframe width="720" height="396" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xX96xng7sAE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p> <p>Check ook <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53glKEPzElA">de video van MinutePhysics</a>.</p>
]]>
</lees-verder>
<image>
http://images.flabber.net/files/linkdump/schrikkeljaarwatishet.jpg
</image>
<pubDate>Wed, 29 Feb 2012 11:19:00 +0100</pubDate>
</item>
```

Thanks a bunch in advance! If you have any questions or if I was not clear enough, just ask and I'll try to clarify!

**IMPORTANT:** I can't use PHP, as Phonegap does not support that. Languages that are accepted: HTML(5), CSS(3) and Javascript (including Jquery, Ajax etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise storing the original xml and then processing it.
This way, you can do something like:
when the user taps on an element you call a function like showElement(id) and then retrieves the details from the stored xml (see it as a master list or database).

This is the way most webapps are made.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help!
Sadly, this is not what I'm looking for, as I'm using a feed from a blog, which updates continuously. 
I got some help on Twitter from someone who says it's possible to parse the whole document, without loading all the content. Then with a "$("#id_title").click()" it should be possible to load on click.
But I have no idea how to parse without loading and then load when clicked. Thanks again!